# How to root Asus Fonepad 8 tablet?

Tags: rooting, asus-fonepad-8

I want to root my tablet Asus Fonepad 8. How do I do it?
I tried iroot, kingoroot, root my device, and etc, but to no avail?

Comment: Use Frama root (the easiest way) or Towel root. Tutorials are all over the web.

Comment: Elaborating that *"and etc,"* would definitely help us to not ending up suggesting those "and etc," again, and see **Methods/apps** [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/1185/96277).